# Ansible-galaxy not working with sudo

Tags: sudo, ansible

I'm having problems instaling plugins with `ansible-galaxy`.

I've tried 3 things:

### Instaling without sudo:

```
ansible-galaxy install sfromm.epel
[WARNING]: - sfromm.epel was NOT installed successfully: Could not update files in /etc/ansible/roles/sfromm.epel: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ansible/roles/sfromm.epel'
```

Nothing weird here, obviously my user can't write in that folder.

---

### Instaling with sudo su:

```
$ sudo su
root@notebook# ansible-galaxy install  sfromm.epel 
- ...
- sfromm.epel was installed successfully
```

As you can see I'm able to install the plugin this way.

---

### Instaling with sudo:

Here is where I don't understand what is happening.

```
$ sudo ansible-galaxy install  sfromm.epel
[WARNING]: - sfromm.epel was NOT installed successfully: The API server (https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/) is not responding, please try again later
```

---

`sudo curl https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/` responds OK. I'm not behind a proxy.

**Could it be a problem with certificates since the API is `https`? How can I know where does ansible pick those from?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing. I worked around it by setting ansible_roles=~/.ansible/roles in my ~/.ansible.cfg file and installing the roles without the need for sudo. Does installing them in a system-wide even make sense in most cases? Still, it's annoying and worked in previous versions of ansible (I'm using 2.1.0.0).

Comment: Had to use roles_path in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.1.10, ansible-galaxy masked error messages connecting to the api server and returned a generic 'server must be down' error.  This has been fixed at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16039 and as of this moment is part of their 2.2 milestone (so presumably it will be released with ansible 2.2).

I had an identical problems as your 'Instaling with sudo' section, and it was due to a badly-formed ~/.netrc file in my user's home directory (which the github PR specifically addresses).  I was able to fix the file and re-run ansible-galaxy and it correctly installed the desired roles.

Something is causing [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c9d2a67ec7b540c9dd59b12ec3f304c032913c83/lib/ansible/module_utils/urls.py#L745) function to raise an unhandled exception [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/011320793bafffe764a07f4e3d9ee66872b32872/lib/ansible/galaxy/api.py#L114), perhaps a read through the code would be helpful.